# slick 2.0 error row._1 error in Scala Intellij IDEA 15.0.2

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, slick-2.0

Below is my slick 2.0 program in Scala IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2.

This program is giving compile time error in IntelliJ IDEA:

> Cannot resolve symbol _1

I am attached the screenshot of the error also.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._

case class User(
                 id: Long,
                 username: String,
                 email: Option[String],
                 password: String,
                 created: Timestamp)

//a simple table called 'users'
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {

  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def username = column[String]("username", O.NotNull)
  // an Option[] in the case class maps to a Nullable field here
  def email = column[String]("email", O.Nullable)
  def password = column[String]("password", O.NotNull)
  // this is a hack for postgresql; if you're using another DB, comment this out
  // and the corresponding field in the case class
  def created = column[Timestamp]("created_at", O.NotNull, O.DBType("timestamp default now()"))

  // usernames should be unique
  def idx = index("users_unique_username", (username), unique = true)

  //define the "shape" of a single data record
  //we're saying that an object of class User (our case class) should be returned
  def * = (id, username, email.?, password,created) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
}

val connectionUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/slick?user=slick&password=slick"
Database.forURL(connectionUrl, driver = "org.postgresql.Driver") withSession {
  implicit session =>
    val users = TableQuery[Users]

    // SELECT * FROM users
    users.list foreach { row =>
      println("user with id " + row._1 + " has username " + row._2)
    }

    // SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='john'
    users.filter(_.username === "john").list foreach { row =>
      println("user whose username is 'john' has id "+row._1 )
    }
}
```

[Slick error in intellij IDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prYLz.png)

When I created the same program in eclipse scala-ide, the program runs fine and fetches the result.

Is this an existing issue or am I missing something on my side?

Comment: It seems to me that row is actually an instance of User. So `._1` should just be `.id`, and `._2` should be `.username`. I have no idea why this would have worked in Eclipse though.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

```
class Users(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {
```

If yor table returned Tuples it would look like

```
Table[(Long, String, Option[String] <...>]
```

And then your

```
println("user with id " + row._1 + " has username " + row._2)
```

would be valid. I think your IDE is somehow misconfigured and runs your old codes. This is how your codes might be fixed to compile and work:

```
// SELECT * FROM users
users.list foreach { user =>
  println("user with id " + user.id + " has username " + user.name)
}


// SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='john'
users.filter(_.username === "john").list foreach { user =>
  println("user whose username is 'john' has id "+ user.id )
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is any issue with the code because the code is same in both intellij IDEA and eclipse scala IDE. Also, scala version is 2.11.7 in both IDEs. For, your suggestion of code we can use Table of any custom clase class object or Tuple of OOB data types. Slick supports both of them.